# Turn 1d-indexed xarray variables into 3D coordinates

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, python-xarray

I have an `xarray.Dataset` that looks roughly like this:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:           (index: 286720)
Coordinates:
  * index             (index) int64 0 1 2 3 4 ... 286716 286717 286718 286719
Data variables:
    Time              (index) float64 2.525 2.525 2.525 ... 9.475 9.475 9.475
    ch                (index) int64 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ... 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
    pixel             (index) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 1020 1021 1022 1023 1024
    Rough_wavelength  (index) float64 2.698 2.701 2.704 ... 32.05 32.05 32.06
    Count             (index) int64 463 197 265 335 305 ... 285 376 278 0 278
```

There are only 140 unique values for the `Time` variable, 2 for the `ch`(...annel), and 1024 for the `pixel` value. I'd thus like to turn them into coordinates and completely drop the largely irrelevant `index` coordinate, something like this:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:           (Time: 140, ch: 2, pixel: 1024)
Coordinates:
    Time              (time) float64 2.525 ... 9.475
    ch                (ch) int64 1 2
    pixel             (pixel) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 1020 1021 1022 1023 1024
Data variables:
    Rough_wavelength  (time, ch, pixel) float64 2.698  ... 32.06
    Count             (time, ch, pixel) int64 463  ...  278
```

Is there a way to do this using xarray? If not, what's a sane way to do this using the standard numpy stack?

Comment: I think we can put together an answer for this question, but a [mre] is always appreciated :)

Comment: Yeah, apologies, seems obvious in hindsight that I should have posted a subset of the data array... will remember next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `index` coordinate with a [`pd.MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object), then [`unstack`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.unstack.html) the index:

```py
In [10]: ds.assign_coords(
    ...:     {
    ...:         "index": pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    ...:             [ds.Time.values, ds.ch.values, ds.pixel.values],
    ...:             names=["Time", "ch", "pixel"],
    ...:         )
    ...:     }
    ...: ).drop_vars(["Time", "ch", "pixel"]).unstack("index")
```

Comment: That does the trick and is lightning fast, thanks a ton! Guess I really need to finally read up on `MultiIndex`, because it looks a bit magical to me at the moment.

Comment: Yeah they're so useful! Note that the pd.MultiIndex link I sent above points to the [advanced user guide: creating a MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object). This is a super helpful reference and a great place to start!